# How to convert thousands of columns to integers?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a dataframe with 10,000+ columns to integers. I have a function that loops through every single column and converts them one by one to integers. This works but it takes a really long time finish. The function:

```
def convert_to_int(dataframe, all_cols):

    for column in all_cols:
        try:
            dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].astype(int)
        except (ValueError, OverflowError):
                pass

    return dataframe
```

Is there a single command that can do this quicker? I have tried pd.to_numeric and ignore the errors, but most columns are not converted to integers. Any ideas?

Edit: To give some insight in my data; Nearly all of my columns are numerical but have a lot of numerical values that are actually strings. Many of my columns are binary, so they contain the values `0, 1, '1', '0'`. These strings have to be converted to integers.

Comment: does `df.astype(int)` work? you can also try `pd.to_numeric(df.stack(), errors='coerce').unstack()`

Comment: When trying `.stack()` I get `AssertionError: Some items were not contained in blocks`

`df.astype(int)` gives me a ValueError because some columns can't be transformed into integers. Hence the try/except statement in my function.

Comment: beside increasing the speed of the type conversion you should split the problem using threads. Try to split the column in `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` buckets and convert them parallel.

Comment: it means you have some duff values, it's really difficult to answer this without a representative example of your data or better a link to your real data. What does `df.info()` currently show? What does the data look like

Comment: See the edit in my main post. Thnx for the help!

Comment: @RF_PY "some columns can't be transformed into integers. " you mean they contain alphanumerics? why don't you then separate them from the ones that can be converted into numbers and set dtype to int.